# CORS error when using a multipart form data

Tags: node.js, express

I handle cors like this in my API :

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:19006'}));
```

Every request is ok except when I try to upload an image using form data.

To handle image upload I use multer like this :

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    
    callback(null, "avatars");
  },

  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    let imagePath = Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);
    callback(null, imagePath);

  
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.use("/uploadAvatar", upload.single("avatar"), (req, res) => {
  
  res.status(200).json(req.file);
});
```

and for the front-end part (its in react native but on web development version) :

```
const pickPicture = async () => {
    let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({});
   

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("avatar", result.file);


    axios
      .post(
        `${BASE_URL}/uploadAvatar`,

        data,

        {
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      )
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(async function (res) {
        

        let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
        
        let picture = res.data.filename;

        axios
          .post(
            `${BASE_URL}/userData/update`,
            {
              token: token,
              picture: picture,
            },

            {
              withCredentials: true,
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
              },
            }
          )
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
        setUserAvatar(picture);
        AsyncStorage.setItem("avatar", picture);
      });
  };
```

The error I get :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myApi/userData/update' from origin 'http://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried a lot of cors options and syntaxes, but nothing worked for the moment.
I'm probably missing something about cors, but what ?

Answer (score 0):

Stop the Node.js server.

***npm install cors*** 
Add following lines to your server.js or index.js

```
const cors = require('cors')

// Use this after the variable declaration
app.use(cors())
```

**Edit**
 if this does not work than you can use CORS middleware like this: 
use a CORS middleware like

```
let allowCors = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "***Your IP***");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
}
```

and apply via

```
    app.use(allowCors);
```

Comment: OP is already using `cors`

Comment: @ardritkrasniqi thanks for your response but its already done,i just don't want to allow all origins

Comment: @ardritkrasniqi I have edited my code with your proposition.
I have the same problem with the image upload part, and the other requests are ok.

Comment: can you change the app.use("/uploadAvatar" .....     to:          
app.post("/uploadAvatar" ....  

app.use is usually used to specify middlewares as callback functions, in the other hand app.post and app.get are used to define routes

Comment: I tried, same problem. I tried to add a res.setHeader with access control inside the app.post but same result

Comment: it seams like th fisrt part of the axios is ok, but the one in the .then gets blocked.

Comment: Any solution to this? I started getting this with Chrome 117 where they apparently have upped the security. The problem only occurrs from localhost and only on routes which uses multer.